# Bootsrap carousel for post

Tags: posts, query-posts, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a Bootsrap carousel to display my post -

They are being display, However, it doesn't work correctly. It doesn't slide basically....

Here is the live example:

http://latitudesadventure.co.uk/novocore/dusty-oak/

I'm using the code below:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php 
  $my_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5');
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>
   <!-- The 1st Loop... -->
   <div class="active item well-blue">
     <div class="offset1">       
     <div class="carousel-image">
     <?php 

if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : 

MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');

endif;

 ?>
 </div>

     <h3 style="color:white;text-align:center"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <h3 style="color:white;text-align:center"> <?php the_field( "number" );  ?></h3>
   </div> 
 </div>
<?php endwhile;
  // The 2nd Loop limits the query to 2 more posts...
$limit_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2');
if($limit_query->have_posts()) : while ($limit_query->have_posts()) : $limit_query->the_post(); 
if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
<!-- The 2nd Loop same data as 1st loop -->
<?php endwhile; endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
  </div>
```

If i select 'post_per-page=1' they all display ( in two rows) however, it still doesn't slide - I would like all the post to be display - sliding one by one with a current status but nothing to do, it doesn't work.

Any help will be amazing,

thank you !

Comment: Wheres your javascript code to make the slider work?

Comment: I don't have any .... thats certainly why :/

Comment: Cool add some javascript. Then let us know how you go.

Answer (score 1):

You have added active class in all slides. Due to this all slides is displaying. You have to add active class to first slides only. Check below bootstrap slider code-

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php 
  $my_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5');
  $count=1;
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
$active= ($count==1? 'active' : '');// this is to add active to the first slider
  ?>
   <!-- The 1st Loop... -->
   <div class="<?php echo $active ?> item well-blue">
     <div class="offset1">       
     <div class="carousel-image">
     <?php 
     $count++;


if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : 

MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');

endif;

 ?>
 </div>

     <h3 style="color:white;text-align:center"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <h3 style="color:white;text-align:center"> <?php the_field( "number" );  ?></h3>
   </div> 
 </div>
<?php endwhile;
  // The 2nd Loop limits the query to 2 more posts...
$limit_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2');
if($limit_query->have_posts()) : while ($limit_query->have_posts()) : $limit_query->the_post(); 
if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
<!-- The 2nd Loop same data as 1st loop -->
<?php endwhile; endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
  </div>
```

I have added a counter to add active class only to your first slide. This should work let me know if it works or not

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time ! Looking better as it slide correctly now :) otherwise it display only one item in the caroussel :( If you had any idea why ?

Thanks for all your help !

Comment: @tibewww as per [link] (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/) you should only have one div with an `active` class at one time. The code you ran put the `active` class in all the div hence the error. If the answer fixed your issue do mark it as answered :)